# How to calculate total area for classified polygons?

Tags: arcgis-10.7

I am trying to calculate the area of landuse types I have classified into 4 classes. I currently have the area for each polygon in the Shape_Area field and the respective class in the gridcode field.

I'd like to know what steps can be done to sum the areas for each class, as I've forgotten how its done.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Summary statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm):

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table

Comment: Thank you,  I was able use Shape_Area as the statistics field and gridcode as the case field to get my info.